# how to use Equatable package on my child class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package

I can use this package to a normal class like this, I can extend it easily

```
class ProductCategory extends Equatable {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        id,
        name,
      ];

  const ProductCategory({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

}
```

but now I have to create a child class from `ProductCategory` like this

```
class ShipmentProductCategory extends ProductCategory with Equatable {
  final ShipmentProductCategoryPrice price;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        id,
        name,
        price,
      ];

  const ShipmentProductCategory({
    required this.price,
    required int id,
    required String name,
  }) : super(id: id, name: name);

}
```

I can't directly extend this child class to Equatable because I use `extend` for inheritance, and I assume I can use `Equatable` package using `with` like the code above

but now I have error message

> The class 'Equatable' can't be used as a mixin because it declares a
> constructor.

[image]

so how to use Equatable on my child class ?

Answer (score 1):

You just only extend 'Equatable' one time at 'ProductCategory' class.

Below test code is changed to non-Null-Safety code and price variable for testing in my environment.

```
class ProductCategory extends Equatable {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        id,
        name,
      ];

  const ProductCategory({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.name,
  });
}

class ShipmentProductCategory extends ProductCategory {
  final int price;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        id,
        name,
        price,
      ];

  const ShipmentProductCategory({
    @required this.price,
    @required int id,
    @required String name,
  }) : super(id: id, name: name);
}
```

Comment: `props` could be implemented with `List<Object> get props => [...super.props, price];`

Answer (score 0):

Use EquitableMixin

```
class ShipmentProductCategory extends ProductCategory with EquatableMixin {
  final ShipmentProductCategoryPrice price;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        id,
        name,
        price,
      ];

  const ShipmentProductCategory({
    required this.price,
    required int id,
    required String name,
  }) : super(id: id, name: name);

}
```